# Many to Many Insert Update and delete I got part of it done (Code First EF 5.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Simple many to many relationship
[image]

Here all the cases that I am trying to accomplish

- case number 1. Both the file and the category are new
- Case number 2. The file is not new and category is not new.
- Case number 3. The file is new but the category is not new
- Case number 4. The file is new but the categirt is not new.

### Case Number 1 solution: everything works fine here

```
    using (MyContext DbCtx = new MyContext())
    {

        var FileCategory = new FileCategory { 
            Active=true, 
            Category="W",  
            File = new List<File>()  
        };
        var File = new File
        {
            FileName = "a",
            FileTypeId = 1,
            RevisionDate = DateTime.Now,
            UploadDate = DateTime.Now,
            FileCategory = new List<FileCategory>()
        };
        DbCtx.FileCategory.Add(FileCategory);
        FileCategory.File.Add(File);
        DbCtx.SaveChanges(); 
    }
```

### Case Number 2: I get an error:NullReferenceException  (

I think FileCategory navigational property is null from the MyExistingFile. Not sure is lazy loading is getting the best of me here.

```
  using (MyContext DbCtx = new MyContext())
            {
                var MyExistingFile = DbCtx.File.Find(1);
                var MyExistingCategory = DbCtx.FileCategory.Find(1);
                //with the line below i am trying to say we dint change anything on File since it already exist
                DbCtx.Entry<File>(MyExistingFile).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                //I am just trying to add the category to a file. Since a file can multiple categories.
                MyExistingFile.FileCategory.Add(MyExistingCategory);
                DbCtx.SaveChanges(); 
            }
```

I am guessing I will be able to solve the rest once someone shows me why case number 2 is wrong.

## Update: Solution was given by  Slauma

I added virtual to all my poco properties and navigational properties like this

```
 public class FileCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int FileCategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Category { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Active { get; set; }    
        public virtual ICollection<File> File { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I was able to write this and it worked for case number 2

```
        using (MyContext DbCtx = new MyContext())
        {
            var MyExistingFile = DbCtx.File.Find(1);
            var MyExistingCategory = DbCtx.FileCategory.Find(1);
            MyExistingFile.FileCategory.Add(MyExistingCategory);
            DbCtx.SaveChanges(); 
        }
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the exception?

Comment: MyExistingFile.FileCategory.Add(MyExistingCategory);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an empty list:

```
using (MyContext DbCtx = new MyContext())
{
    var MyExistingFile = DbCtx.File.Find(1);
    var MyExistingCategory = DbCtx.FileCategory.Find(1);
    MyExistingFile.FileCategory = new List<FileCategory>();
    MyExistingFile.FileCategory.Add(MyExistingCategory);
    DbCtx.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

It's actually better to avoid lazy loading in this scenario because it would load the `FileCategory` collection from the database. But you don't need this collection to create the new relationship.

Manually setting the state to `Unchanged` is not necessary, so I removed that line.

Comment: Why does this work? Because you created an empty list? I have to create an object assign it to a null reference then add my value ? How does this work?

Comment: @jvelez: Because you guessed that `MyExistingFile.FileCategory` is `null`. I followed your guess. (Actually `MyExistingFile` could be `null` as well if there is no entity with Id `1` in the database. You need to check in the debugger what really is `null`.) If `MyExistingFile.FileCategory` is `null` you probably don't have marked that collection as `virtual`, hence lazy loading doesn't work und you need to create the list manually.